# pass data from app to control extension (smartwatch)

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I would like to send some data (string) from Android application to my Smartwatch extension.

I create an Intent in my Main Activity and send it using startService().

From that I understand, I have to override  onStartCommand() in a class that extends ExtensionService.

My question is how my class that extends ControlExtension will be notify of this Intent ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to use a broadcast receiver. Register a receiver in your control and filter for the intent you send. (Instead of calling startService you should send your intent as a broadcast).

You can create and broadcast your intent with

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.super.cool.intent.name");
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

and then filter with:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("my.super.cool.intent.name");
```

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but if I understand correctly my class that extends BroadcastReceiver should filter the intent and setClass to my controlExtension. Which method should I use to coolect my intent in my controlExtension ? If by chance you have an example it will be great =)

Comment: Thanks =) It works perfectly. I just have a new (and quick) question. I don't need (so far) to have a class that extends ExtensionService ?

Comment: Yes you do, you need the service. Its used for many different things. For example it is vital in the registration process of the extension.